# PIL Alternative to saving / overwriting pixels?

Tags: python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

I'm using Python3, but I'm not very experienced with it yet. I would like to change pixels with a certain color in jpg and png files. That already works wonderfully with PIL / Image.

```
im = self.open_image(‘myPicture’)
im.putpixel((x, y), (r, g, b))
```

However, I would like to overwrite these changes directly (binary) in the original image (or a 1: 1 copy of it) instead of saving the entire image as jpg or png.

Something more like this:

```
f = open(‘myPicture’, “wb")
f.write(...)
```

…
Instead of:

```
im.save(‘myPicture’, "PNG")
```

The reason for this is that I wanted to leave the rest of the image unchanged, and that means no compression (jpg) or changing the file size. I just want to replace a few RGB values for certain pixels.

What's the best way to do this? How do I find the file offset where the pixel data start in a jpg or png file? And are they saved there in the same format (in sequence) as in my image object (im).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You want to change the content of a compressed file directly?  Good luck with that.

Comment: As Scott said, image files are compressed, and often also checksummed, so you can't change one part without upsetting the rest.